# Date that is one year from another date

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm trying to calculate the date that is a year from the current date:

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let currDate = NSDate()
let newDate = calendar.dateBySettingUnit(.Year, value: 2017, ofDate: currDate, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))!
```

But `newDate` is always January 1, 2017.

Comment: Why the foo with the raw value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got it almost

```
let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
let currDate = NSDate()
let newDate = calendar.dateByAddingUnit(.Year, value: 1, toDate: currDate, options: [])
```

Comment: Any ideas why `dateBySettingUnit` doesn't work as expected? I still need `dateBySettingUnit` for related calculations.

Comment: Yes, as the method name implies, you're **setting** the year unit of the current year to 2017.

Comment: But I'm not touching the day and the current day is Jan 31. Why teh result is Jan 1 then?

Comment: That's indeed weird. The documentation says *If no such time exists for the specified components, the next available date is returned, which may be on a different calendar day* but there is a valid date one year ahead.

Comment: Weird, indeed. Thanks anyways!